# DISTRIBUTED_LOCK_TIMEOUT recommended value in Oracle

Tags: oracle

1. What is the recommended value for DISTRIBUTED_LOCK_TIMEOUT where its default is 60?
   2.Whether we can increase as per for application requirements?
   3.What are the side effects of increasing this numbers?

Comment: Why do you need to increase it?

Comment: we are hitting distributed transaction waiting for lock exception ORA 02049 very often in concurrency test